# Django-registation : Error on activate new user

Tags: django, url-routing

I'm using Django registration inside my project on a development server.
When I register a new user, I use EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend' to get the activation link.
When I try to put the activation link into the web browser, I have an error, and the account is not activated.

It is said : [image: Error not found]

Thank you.
This function is used to generate the key.

```
def create_profile(self, user):
    """
    Create a ``RegistrationProfile`` for a given
    ``User``, and return the ``RegistrationProfile``.

    The activation key for the ``RegistrationProfile`` will be a
    SHA1 hash, generated from a combination of the ``User``'s
    username and a random salt.

    """
    salt = hashlib.sha1(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
    username = user.username
    if isinstance(username, unicode):
        username = username.encode('utf-8')
    activation_key = hashlib.sha1(salt+username).hexdigest()
    return self.create(user=user,
                       activation_key=activation_key)
```

I received that mail. But I use EMAIL_BACKEND'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'.

I think the problem comes from here. But I can't test in production server.

[image: Mail received]

I solved the problem actually It's because I generate the email to send inside a file thanks to the file email backends provided by django for development purpose. Inside this file, when there is a carriage return, it adds an = characters. And this is the case with the link to active the account.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please be aware that tags are not keywords.  That is, stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question title does not help people find your question.  Please select your tags with care.  For example, this question is actually about an error while routing a URL inside Django.

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind next time.

Comment: "Inside this file, when there is a carriage return, it adds an = characters." I get that sometimes as well; it's what happens when the line is too long. Not sure why. Anyway, glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have a `=` character in your activation key.

Although `sergzach`'s answer will work, I'd be more interested in finding out why that `=` is there in the first place.

`django-registration` [usually generates the key as follows](https://code.google.com/p/django-registration/source/browse/trunk/registration/models.py):

```
        salt = sha.new(str(random.random())).hexdigest()[:5]
        activation_key = sha.new(salt+user.username).hexdigest()
```

Where are you generating yours?

Comment: I added the function which generate the key from models.py in the question description.

Comment: You are right, the account didn't activate with = on the link, but it worked when I retrieved it !! I don't konw why. I am going to check.

Comment: I solved the problem actually It's because I generate the email to send inside a file thanks to the file email backends provided by django for development purpose. Inside this file, when there is a carriage return, it adds an = characters. And this is the case with the link to active the account.

Answer (score 0):

The character '=' is not in the range of \w+. Use [\w=]+ instead of \w+.

Replace **?P<activation_key>\w+** to **?P<activation_key>[\w=]+**

Comment: Actually I added {{ }} inside the activation link. But that was not the picture I wanted to show you !

Comment: @user1507156 I have changed my answer. Please view it.

Comment: It worked for finding the template, but the true error was that there were an = inside the activation link. Because using this, the count couldn't be activated. It displayed activation failed.But thank you for your help.